I can't configure the Cmake file for the SDL2 library in Clion
I can't add the SDL2 library to the main.c file. I found an article from which I copied everything except the name of the project. But I still get an error. tell me what the problem is.
enter image description here
project structure:
sdl_game
cmake-build-debug
external
SDL-release-2.30.9
external
SDL-release-2.30.9
CMakeLists.txt
main.c
SDL2.dll(I threw it thinking it would help)
CMakeLists.txt code:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(sdl_game)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(sdl_game main.c)

add_subdirectory(external/SDL-release-2.30.9)

target_link_libraries(sdl_game PRIVATE SDL2)
if (WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(sdl_game PRIVATE SDL2main)
endif ()

add_custom_command(
        TARGET sdl_game POST_BUILD COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        cmake -E copy_if_different
        $<TARGET_FILE:SDL2>
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:sdl_game>
        VERBATIM
)

main.c code:
#include "stdio.h"
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    //this function just exists
    //I haven't come up with the code yet
    return 0;
}


FAILED: sdl_game.exe
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.4\bin\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -g  CMakeFiles/sdl_game.dir/main.c.obj -o sdl_game.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libsdl_game.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  external/SDL-release-2.30.9/libSDL2d.dll.a  external/SDL-release-2.30.9/libSDL2maind.a  -lshell32  -Wl,--undefined=WinMain  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\artem\CLionProjects\sdl_game\cmake-build-debug && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy_if_different cmake -E copy_if_different C:/Users/artem/CLionProjects/sdl_game/cmake-build-debug/external/SDL-release-2.30.9/SDL2d.dll C:/Users/artem/CLionProjects/sdl_game/cmake-build-debug""
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion2024.1.4\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: external/SDL-release-2.30.9/libSDL2maind.a(SDL_windows_main.c.obj): in function OutOfMemory': C:/Users/artem/CLionProjects/sdl_game/external/SDL-release-2.30.9/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:25: undefined reference to SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion2024.1.4\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: external/SDL-release-2.30.9/libSDL2maind.a(SDL_windows_main.c.obj): in function main_getcmdline': C:/Users/artem/CLionProjects/sdl_game/external/SDL-release-2.30.9/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:62: undefined reference to SDL_wcslen'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion2024.1.4\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/artem/CLionProjects/sdl_game/external/SDL-release-2.30.9/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:62: undefined reference to SDL_iconv_string' C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion2024.1.4\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/artem/CLionProjects/sdl_game/external/SDL-release-2.30.9/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:66: undefined reference to SDL_strlen'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion2024.1.4\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/artem/CLionProjects/sdl_game/external/SDL-release-2.30.9/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:71: undefined reference to SDL_memcpy' C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion2024.1.4\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/artem/CLionProjects/sdl_game/external/SDL-release-2.30.9/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:72: undefined reference to SDL_free'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion2024.1.4\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/artem/CLionProjects/sdl_game/external/SDL-release-2.30.9/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:77: undefined reference to `SDL_SetMainReady'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I'm still new to programming and I couldn't figure out how to connect libraries in C/C++ until the end. I don't really like the connection method via settings in VS because I don't understand what and why, cmake seems more "transparent" to me in this regard.

this post problem is,- posting images insteed of text.
